# How to loop tab in Selenium - PHP Webdriver

Tags: php, selenium, webdriver

I have an array contain 10 links, and must access 10 links to get facebook pixel code.

I use selenium to loop 10 links, but it throw error:

```
"stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document".
```

So now I open new tab for 10 links. But how can I loop 10 tabs or move to any tab of them explicitly.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can store all the current tabs in a array and then loop over it to perform any action. Example for switching over the tabs:

```
    $handles = $driver->getWindowHandles();
    foreach ($handles as $handle) {
    $driver->switchTo()->window($handle); 
     }
```

Before switching through the tabs, always store your parent window tab somewhere :

```
$parent_tab= $session->getWindowHandle();
```

And when you are done with switching over the tabs, switch back to your parent tab:

```
$driver->switchTo()->window($parent_tab);
```